# raising an Exception in an Except without calling the original Exception

Tags: python, exception, nested, raise

My code is the following:

```
try:
    *Do something*
except *anError*:
    if (condition):
        methodCalled()
    else:
        raise "my own Exception"
```

The problem is that when I raise my own exception ("my own Exception"), the "anError" exception also gets raised. Is there a way to make sure that Error that I caught doesn't get raised when I raise my own Exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/exceptions.html?highlight=__context__):

> When raising (or re-raising) an exception in an except or finally
>   clause __context__ is automatically set to the last exception caught;
>   if the new exception is not handled the traceback that is eventually
>   displayed will include the originating exception(s) and the final
>   exception.

This is exactly your case:

```
try:
    try:
        raise ValueError
    except ValueError:
        raise TypeError
except Exception as e:
    print('Original:', type(e.__context__)) # Original: <class 'ValueError'>
    print('Explicitly raised:', type(e))    # Explicitly raised: <class 'TypeError'>
```

There's only one *active* exception; I might have written `except TypeError` instead of `except Exception` and the output would still be the same.

If you want to prevent Python from printing the original exception, use [`raise  ... from None`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0409/):

```
try:
    raise ValueError
except ValueError:
    raise TypeError from None
```